# Create and then edit file in Ansible problems (authorized_keys)

Tags: ansible, edit, createfile, authorized-keys

I'm doing two easy tasks with ansible.

First i create a new file with content (i exect how role):

```
- name: Add keys to authorized_keys
  blockinfile:
        owner: user
        group: user
        mode: '0600'
        create: yes
        path: /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys
        block: |
                line if text
                other line
                more lines
```

Second task (i exect how second role):

```
- name: Add more keys to authorized_keys root
  blockinfile:
        path: /home/user/.ssh/test_keys
        block: |
                other and more keys
```

The problem is that when executing the second task, the existing lines in the file are deleted and only those of the second task remain. 
What should I do to add the new lines and not delete the existing ones?

Comment: FWIW, Ansible has a dedicated `authorized_key` module: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/authorized_key_module.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *"Existing lines in the file are deleted and only those of the second task remain. What should I do to add the new lines and not delete the existing ones?"*

A: Set unique `marker_begin` and `marker_end` of the blocks. For example

```
- name: Add keys to authorized_keys
  blockinfile:
    marker_begin: "BEGIN BLOCK1"
    marker_end: "END BLOCK1"
    owner: user
    group: user
    mode: '0600'
    create: yes
    path: /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys
    block: |
      line if text
      other line
      more lines

- name: Add more keys to authorized_keys root
  blockinfile:
    marker_begin: "BEGIN BLOCK2"
    marker_end: "END BLOCK2"
    path: /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys
    block: |
      other and more keys
```